strategy won't buy at target price given
my logic is simple, buy some orders are not excuted at target price, like btc price below 40k. In the picture, only some orders are being excuted properly. Can anyone help me understand why my buy orders are not being executed? Any insights into what might be wrong with the logic or how to debug this further would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
//@version=5
strategy("BTC Buy on Dip", overlay=true)


start = timestamp(2022,1,1,0,0,0)
var float equity = 1000000
var initialPrice = 48000

if time > start and low < 45600
    // buy
    strategy.entry("1", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 45600, limit = 45600)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "1", limit = (initialPrice - 45600) / 2 + 45600)

else if time > start and low < 43200
    // buy
    strategy.entry("2", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 43200 * 1, limit = 43200)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "2", limit = (initialPrice - 43200) / 2 + 43200)

else if time > start and low < 40800
    // buy
    strategy.entry("3", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 40800 * 2, limit = 40800)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "3", limit = (initialPrice - 40800) / 2 + 40800)


else if time > start and low < 38400
    // buy
    strategy.entry("4", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 38400 * 4, limit = 38400)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "4", limit = (initialPrice - 38400) / 2 + 38400)

else if time > start and low < 36000
    // buy
    strategy.entry("5", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 36000 * 8, limit = 36000)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "5", limit = (initialPrice - 36000) / 2 + 36000)


else if time > start and low < 33600
    // buy
    strategy.entry("6", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 33600 * 16, limit = 33600)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "6", limit = (initialPrice - 33600) / 2 + 33600)


else if time > start and low < 31200
    // buy
    strategy.entry("8", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 31200 * 32, limit = 31200)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "8", limit = (initialPrice - 31200) / 2 + 31200)


else if time > start and low < 28800
    // buy
    strategy.entry("9", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 28800 * 64, limit = 28800)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "9", limit = (initialPrice - 28800) / 2 + 28800)

else if time > start and low < 26400
    // buy
    strategy.entry("105", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 26400 * 128, limit = 26400)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "10", limit = (initialPrice - 26400) / 2 + 26400)

else if time > start and low < 24000
    // buy
    strategy.entry("11", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 24000 * 256, limit = 24000)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "11", limit = (initialPrice - 24000) / 2 + 24000)

else if time > start and low < 21600
    // buy
    strategy.entry("12", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 21600 * 512, limit = 21600)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "12", limit = (initialPrice - 21600) / 2 + 21600)

else if time > start and low < 19200
    // buy
    strategy.entry("13", strategy.long, qty=equity / 500 / 19200 * 1024, limit = 19200)
    strategy.exit('sell', from_entry = "13", limit = (initialPrice - 19200) / 2 + 19200)




There is no need to create a strategy to buy. The alert field uses the price through and the custom alert is the best. If it is a simple logic, it is best to convert it to an indicator to minimize bugs.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
